# Support for JMS message selector in azure service bus

Tags: azureservicebus

Currently it appears that azure service bus is not honouring message selector options available in JMS.When will this be supported?FYI we are using apache qpid JMS api to consume message from azure service bus.

Using Apache Qpid 's JMS API, we have created message producer and consumer for azure service bus topic and queue.We tried the message selector option in JMS but it appears that azure service bus does not filter messages based on these options.Would like to know when will it be supported?

#### Consumer side

create a topic named topicname

```
Topic topic = session.createTopic("topicname");
// set filter options using message selector
String filterOption = "country = 'US' AND state = 'California'"

MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic,filterOption);
```

#### Publisher Side code

```
TopicSession topicSession = topicConn.createTopicSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// create a topic publisher
TopicPublisher topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
topicPublisher.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
// create the "Hello World" message
TextMessage message = topicSession.createTextMessage();
message.setText("hello world");
// Set two properties country and state
message.setStringProperty("country","US");
message.setStringProperty("state","New Jersey");
// Publish the message
topicPublisher.publish(message);
```

In the above example, since the filter option is set to receive message only when the message property has country set to `'US'` and state set to `'California'`. But with azure service bus , this filter option is not being honoured and as a result the consumer gets all messages published to that queue.

Comment: Is the filter create on Azure Service Bus broker side?

Comment: Hi,Filter is created while creating consumer but its an instruction to broker to filter messages.The same conde works fine with Active Mq but with Azure Service Bus its now working.So its a limitation only with Azure Service Bus.Their documentation says that message filtering is not supported via JMS as of now.But would like to know when would it be supported as its an important feature

Comment: Kindly appreciate any update on this.

Comment: Suggest opening a support case with Microsoft to find out answer to your question. Externals cannot answer what Microsoft is planning internally 